# Adding a background image to the Circle patch in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to load an image file and use it as background image to a circle created by matplotlib circle patch?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))   
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   
ci = Circle((2, -2), 5)   
ax.add_patch(ci)   
ax.annotate('1', xy=(2, -2), xycoords = 'data', xytext=(-2, 3),size=20, textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="fancy", fc="0.8", ec="0.6", patchB=el,connectionstyle="angle3,angleA=0,angleB=-90"),)
plt.show()
```

In other words, I would like the circle in this plot have an image as background:

[image: plot]

Comment: There is an [example in the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo_clip_path.html). In how far does this not solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be working. How can I scale the image to fit in the circle? And also how to keep the circle line? It automatically removes it.

Comment: You would need 2 circles, one to set the clip path, the other to stay in the image as "border". Scaling the image should be possible with the `extent` keyword to `imshow`. If it isn't working, I'd suggest you edit your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It is working fine now.

Comment: If you have a working solution now, you may either delete this question or you can post your solution as an answer and accept it, such that the question is not left as unanswered in the list.